# Unable to setup replica sets in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, database-connection, replicaset

The original question is being edited.

Edit: so i figured out the problem. The db for the application has been setup as replica sets and that's what is missing here. I followed all steps mentioned in the article https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/
but am now not able to setup replica sets

```
 [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval: config.system.sessions does not exist
2019-08-12T09:32:27.102+0530 I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions reap interval: config.system.sessions does not exist
2019-08-12T09:32:27.103+0530 I CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Sessions collection is not set up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Replication has not yet been configured
```

this is what i get when running command

```
mongod --replSet rsSpeQue --port 27017 --bind_ip localhost --dbpath \SpeQueRS\rsSpeQue1 --smallfiles --oplogSize 128
```

to setup replica set on port 27017. Output of command > db.runCommand("getCmdLineOpts")

```
{
        "argv" : [
                "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.0\\bin\\mongod.exe",
                "--config",
                "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.0\\bin\\mongod.cfg",
                "--service"
        ],
        "parsed" : {
                "config" : "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.0\\bin\\mongod.cfg",
                "net" : {
                        "bindIp" : "127.0.0.1",
                        "port" : 27017
                },
                "service" : true,
                "storage" : {
                        "dbPath" : "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.0\\data",
                        "journal" : {
                                "enabled" : true
                        }
                },
                "systemLog" : {
                        "destination" : "file",
                        "logAppend" : true,
                        "path" : "C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.0\\log\\mongod.log"
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

basically the replica sets are not being setup. What am i missing here??

Comment: ```2019-08-10T03:30:19.662+0530 I NETWORK [conn719] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:54745 conn719: { driver: { name: "mongo-csharp-driver", version: "2.8.1.0" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134", architecture: "x86_64", version: "10.0.17134" }, platform: ".NET Core 4.6.27817.03" }
2019-08-10T03:34:23.113+0530 I NETWORK [conn719] end connection 127.0.0.1:54745 (0 connections now open)
```
above two lines are from mongod.log.. as can be seen the connection is established but it soon ends with the exception thrown

Answer (score -1):

Since you haven't given any C# code and nu-gets you have installed in your .NET Core 2.2 app, I am giving a generic answer in here. Try out the below things and let me know if that works out fine:

1. Change the connectionString in appsettings.Development.json for MongoDB like below:

   ```
   "ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "mongodb://localhost:27017?connect=replicaSet"
   ```

   }
2. Ensure that you have the below Nuget's installed (Not all are mandatorily required but have it handy for future operations):

   ```
       <PackageReference Include="mongocsharpdriver" Version="2.7.3" />
       <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Bson" Version="2.7.3" />
       <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.7.3" />
       <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver.Core" Version="2.7.3" />
   ```
3. Then, ensure that the C# syntax code is something like below:

   `var client = new MongoClient(_configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value);
               mongoDatabase = client.GetDatabase("myDb");
               offerCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("myCollection");`

Comment: Hi @vamsee thanks for the response but I figured out the problem is with Mongo DB Replica sets.. the db hasnt been setup as stand alone but as replica sets.. I followed steps mentioned in this tutorial https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/ but not able to create replica sets ..pls see details in the original question which i am going to edit